# where these formulas for Legendre polynomials and series come from?

Tags: special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I am reading a textbook on differential equations.The chapter I am studying now is about solving differential equations using series.The book solves Legendre's differential equation$$(1-x^{2})y''-2xy'+v(v+1)y=0$$  using the series method. First, it assumes that the equation has a solution in the form of$$y=c_{0}+c_{1}x+c_{2}x^{2}+\cdots+c_{n}x^{n}+\cdots$$
Then takes the first and second derivatives of $y$ and puts them in the equation $(1-x^{2})y''-2xy'+v(v+1)y=0$ to get the coefficients $c_{i}$.
we have$$y'=c_{1}+2c_{2}x+3c_{3}x^{2}+\cdots+nc_{n}x^{n-1}\cdots$$
and
$$y''=2c_{2}+3\times 2c_{3}x+4\times 3c_{4}x^{2}+\cdots+n(n+1)c_{n}x^{n-2}+\cdots$$
Now put these expressions in the equation$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2c_{2}+3\times 2c_{3}x+4\times 3c_{4}x^{2}+\cdots+(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}x^{n}+\cdots$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -2c^{2}x^{2}-\cdots-n(n-1)c_{n}x^{n}-\cdots$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -2c_{1}x-2\times 2c_{2}x^{2}-\cdots-2nc_{n}x^{n}-\cdots$$
$$+v(v+1)c_{0}+v(v+1)c_{1}x+v(v+1)c_{2}x^{2}+\cdots+v(v+1)c_{n}x^{n}+\cdots=0$$
Equating the coefficient of each power of x to zero, we have
$$2c_{2}+v(v+1)c_{0}=0\Rightarrow c_{2}=-{{v(v+1)}\over{2}}c_{0}$$
$$3\times 2c_{3}-2c_{1}+v(v+1)c_{1}=0\Rightarrow c_{3}=-{{(v-1)(v+2)}\over{3!}}c_{1}$$
$$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$$
$$(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}+\left[{-n(n-1)-2n+v(v+1)}\right]c_{n}=0\Rightarrow c_{n+2}=-{{(v-n)(v+n+1)}\over{(n+2)(n+1)}}c_{n}$$
The last relation is a recursive relation. Using the recursive relation, all odd coefficients are expressed in terms of $c_{1}$ and all even coefficients are expressed in terms of $c_{0}$ and $c_{0}$ and $c_{1}$ are arbitrary constants.So we have:
$$c_{4}=-{{(v-2)(v+3)}\over{4\times 3}}c_{2}={{(v-2)v(v+1)(v+3)}\over{4!}}c_{0}$$
$$c_{5}=-{{(v-3)(v+4)}\over{5\times 4}}c_{3}={{(v-3)(v-1)(v+2)(v+4)}\over{5!}}c_{1}$$
And the rest of the coefficients are calculated in the same way. By inserting these expressions for the coefficients into $y=c_{0}+c_{1}x+c_{2}x^{2}+\cdots+c_{n}x^{n}+\cdots$ we obtain
$$y=c_{0}(1-{{v(v+1)}\over{2!}}x^{2}+{{(v-2)v(v+1)(v+3)}\over{4!}}x^{4}-+\cdots )$$
$$\ \ \ +c_{1}(x-{{(v-1)(v+2)}\over{3!}}x^{3}+{{(v-3)(v-1)(v+2)(v+4)}\over{5!}}x^{5}-+\cdots )$$
We notice that the general solution is in the form
$$y(x)=c_{0}R_{v}(x)+c_{1}S_{v}(x)$$
where $R_{v}(x)$ and $S_{v}(x)$ are two linearly independent solutions.
If $v=n$ (a non-negative integer), then according to the recursive relation $c_{n+2}=-{{(v-n)(v+n+1)}\over{(n+2)(n+1)}}c_{n}$, we have
$$c_{n+2}=c_{n+4}=\cdots=0$$
As a result, when n is even, the series $R_{n}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n and $S_{n}(x)$ will be a series, and when $n$ is odd, the series $S_{n}(x)$ will be a polynomial of degree $n$ and $R_{n}(x)$ will be a series. Therefore, for every non-negative integer n, either $R_{n}(x)$ or $S_{n}(x)$ (and not both) is a polynomial of degree n. These polynomials, after being multiplied by some constants, are called **Legendre polynomials** and are denoted by $P_{n}(x)$. We write the recursive relation $c_{n+2}=-{{(v-n)(v+n+1)}\over{(n+2)(n+1)}}c_{n}$ in the form $$c_{n}=-{{(n+2)(n+1)}\over{(v-n)(v+n+1)}}c_{n+2}$$
Then we obtain all the non-zero coefficients in terms of $c_{v}$. In this case, $c_{v}$ is an arbitrary constant and it is customary to choose
$$c_{v}={{(2v)!}\over{2^{v}(v!)^{2}}}={{1\times 3\times 5\times\cdots\times (2v-1)}\over{v!}}$$
Now, according to relation $c_{n}=-{{(n+2)(n+1)}\over{(v-n)(v+n+1)}}c_{n+2}$, we have:
$$c_{v-2}=-{{v(v-1)}\over{2(2v-1)}}c_{v}=-{{v(v-1)}\over{2(2v-1)}}{{(2v)!}\over{2^{v}(v!)^{2}}}$$
$$=-{{v(v-1)(2v)(2v-1)(2v-2)!}\over{2(2v-1)2^{v}v(v-1)!v(v-1)(v-2)!}}$$
$$=-{{(2v-2)!}\over{2^{v}(v-1)!(v-2)!}}$$
And in a similar way
$$c_{v-4}=-{{(v-2)(v-3)}\over{4(2v-3)}}c_{v-2}={{(v-2)(v-3)}\over{4(2v-3)}}{{(2v-2)!}\over{2^{v}(v-1)!(v-2)!}}$$
$$={{(2v-4)!}\over{2^{v}2!(v-2)!(v-4)!}}$$
and in the general case for $v-2k\geq 0$ we have
$$c_{v-2k}=(-1)^{k}{{(2v-2k)!}\over{2^{v}k!(v-k)!(v-2k)!}}$$
and assuming that $v$ is a non-negative integer like $n$, the resulting solution is called a Legendre polynomial of degree $n$ and we denote it by $P_{n}(x)$ and according to the relation $c_{v-2k}=(-1)^{k}{{(2v-2k)!}\over{2^{v}k!(v-k)!(v-2k)!}}$, we have
$$P_{n}(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left[{{{n}\over{2}}}\right]}{(-1)^{k}{{(2n-2k)!}\over{2^{n}k!(n-k)!(n-2k)!}}}x^{n-2k}$$
So the general solution of a Legendre equation with $v=n$ is
$$y=a_{1}P_{n}(x)+a_{2}Q_{n}(x)$$
where $P_{n}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n which is calculated by the formula $P_{n}(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left[{{{n}\over{2}}}\right]}{(-1)^{k}{{(2n-2k)!}\over{2^{n}k!(n-k)!(n-2k)!}}}x^{n-2k}$ and q is an infinite series. We call $P_{n}(x)$'s Legendre polynomials and $Q_{n}(x)$'s second type Legendre functions.

**So far everything is clear** but after this book says:
As we said before, the general solution of Legendre's equation is in general form
$$y(x)=c_{0}\left[{{\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{\infty}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it v}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 2}{\rm ))...(}{\it v}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}{\it v}{\rm (}{\it v}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it v}+{\rm 3}{\rm )...(}{\it v}+{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}{\rm )!}}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}{\it k}}}\right]$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +c_{1}\left[{{\rm x}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{\infty}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it v}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))...(}{\it v}-{\rm 3}{\rm )(v}{\rm -}{\rm 1)(}{\it v}+2{\rm )(}{\it v}+4{\rm )...(}{\it v}+2k{\rm )}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k+1}{\rm )!}}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}{\it k+1}}}\right]$$
$$=c_{0}R_{v}(x)+c_{1}S_{v}(x)$$
and when $v=n$ ($n$ a non-negative integer) either $R_{n}(x)$ or $S_{n}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and as it was said before, we denote these polynomials with $P_{n}(x)$. $P_{n}(x)$ can be obtained from the following equation:
$$P_{n}(x)=\left\{{\matrix{
{{{R_{n}(x)}\over{R_{n}(1)}},even\ n}\cr
{{{S_{n}(x)}\over{S_{x}(1)}},\ odd\ n}\cr
}}\right.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
And the other solution, which is an infinite series and is denoted by $Q_{n}(x)$, can be obtained from the following relation:
$$Q_{n}(x)=\left\{{\matrix{
{R_{n}(1)S_{n}(x)\ \ \ ,even\ n}\cr
{-S_{x}(1)R_{n}(x),\ \ \ odd\ n}\cr
}}\right.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
**This is where I run into trouble.** **The book does not explain where formulas 1 and 2 came from.**

These formulas are equivalent to say that for even ${\it n}$, Legendre polynomials ${\it P}_{{\it n}}{\rm (}{\it x}{\rm )}$ are obtained from this formula:
$${{{\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{{{{\it n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it n}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 2}{\rm ))...(}{\it n}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}{\it n}{\rm (}{\it n}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it n}+{\rm 3}{\rm )...(}{\it n}+{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}{\rm )!}}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}{\it k}}}\over{{\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{{{{\it n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it n}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 2}{\rm ))...(}{\it n}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}{\it n}{\rm (}{\it n}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it n}+{\rm 3}{\rm )...(}{\it n}+{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}{\rm )!}}}}}}={\it P}_{{\it n}}{\rm (}{\it x}{\rm )}$$
(provided that ${\it n}$ be even) for example:$${\it P}_{{\rm 4}}{\rm (}{\it x}{\rm )}={{{\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{{\rm 2}}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it 4}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 2}{\rm ))...(}{\it 4}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}{\it 4}{\rm (}{\it 4}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it 4}+{\rm 3}{\rm )...(}{\it 4}+{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}{\rm )!}}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}{\it k}}}\over{{\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{{\rm 2}}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it 4}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 2}{\rm ))...(}{\it 4}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}{\it 4}{\rm (}{\it 4}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it 4}+{\rm 3}{\rm )...(}{\it 4}+{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}{\rm )!}}}}}}={{{\rm 1}+{{-{\rm 1}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm 5}}\over{{\rm 2}{\rm !}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}}+{{{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm 5}{\rm \times}{\rm 7}}\over{{\rm 4}{\rm !}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 4}}}\over{{\rm 1}+{{-{\rm 1}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm 5}}\over{{\rm 2}{\rm !}}}+{{{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm 5}{\rm \times}{\rm 7}}\over{{\rm 4}{\rm !}}}}}={{{\rm 1}-{\rm 10}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}}+{{{\rm 35}}\over{{\rm 3}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 4}}}\over{{\rm 1}-{\rm 10}+{{{\rm 35}}\over{{\rm 3}}}}}={{{\rm 3}}\over{{\rm 8}}}{\rm (}{\rm 1}-{\rm 10}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}}+{{{\rm 35}}\over{{\rm 3}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 4}}{\rm )}={{{\rm 1}}\over{{\rm 8}}}{\rm (}{\rm 3}-{\rm 30}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}}+{\rm 35}{\it x}^{{\rm 4}}{\rm )}$$
and for odd ${\it n}$,    Legendre polynomials ${\it P}_{{\it n}}{\rm (}{\it x}{\rm )}$ are obtained from this formula: $${{{\rm x}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{\left[{{{n}\over{2}}}\right]}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it n}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))...(}{\it n}-{\rm 3}{\rm )(n}{\rm -}{\rm 1)(}{\it n}+2{\rm )(}{\it n}+4{\rm )...(}{\it n}+2k{\rm )}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k+1}{\rm )!}}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}{\it k+1}}}\over{{\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{\left[{{{n}\over{2}}}\right]}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it n}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))...(}{\it n}-{\rm 3}{\rm )(n}{\rm -}{\rm 1)(}{\it n}+2{\rm )(}{\it n}+4{\rm )...(}{\it n}+2k{\rm )}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k+1}{\rm )!}}}}}}={\it P}_{{\it n}}{\rm (}{\it x}{\rm )}$$(provided that n be odd) In this formula, $\left[{{{n}\over{2}}}\right]$ is the largest integer smaller than ${{n}\over{2}}$. for example:$${\it P}_{{\it 5}}{\rm (}{\it x}{\rm )}{\rm =}{{{\rm x}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{2}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it 5}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))...(}{\it 5}-{\rm 3}{\rm )(5}{\rm -}{\rm 1)(}{\it 5}+2{\rm )(}{\it 5}+4{\rm )...(}{\it 5}+2k{\rm )}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k+1}{\rm )!}}}}{\it x}^{{\rm 2}{\it k+1}}}\over{{\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{2}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}{\rm (}{\it 5}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm ))...(}{\it 5}-{\rm 3}{\rm )(5}{\rm -}{\rm 1)(}{\it 5}+2{\rm )(}{\it 5}+4{\rm )...(}{\it 5}+2k{\rm )}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k+1}{\rm )!}}}}}}={{x+{{-1\times 4\times 7}\over{3!}}x^{3}+{{2\times 4\times 7\times 9}\over{5!}}x^{5}}\over{1+{{-1\times 4\times 7}\over{3!}}+{{2\times 4\times 7\times 9}\over{5!}}}}={{x-{{14}\over{3}}x^{3}+{{21}\over{5}}x^{5}}\over{1-{{14}\over{3}}+{{21}\over{5}}}}={{15}\over{8}}(x-{{14}\over{3}}x^{3}+{{21}\over{5}}x^{5})={{1}\over{8}}(15x-70x^{3}+63x^{5})$$ which is also true.
I want to prove these two formulas(1 & 2).If you can, please help me or if you know a textbook that mentions these two formulas, please introduce it to me. thanks

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813)

Comment: Props for getting the formulas TeXified! For someone wanting to help you a key (or a stumbling block) may be how the Legendre polynomials were defined in your book/class? As a system of orthogonal polynomials with respect to an inner product, normalized one way or another? Via a recurrence relation? By a generating function? Rodrigues' formula?

Comment: You could add details like that to the question body to thwart criticism. Also the story of how you ran into this question :-=

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I edited the question and added the things you pointed out. I think my question is clear enough now. As you can see, the solution of Legendre's differential equation is defined by a recursive relation. But at the end, a formula has been introduced without any additional explanation

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I upvoted your question a while ago when I noticed how serious you are about this :-)

Comment: looks like nobody knows the answer. I think it's better to ask this question again so that maybe someone can answer